# Flutter Async Load Multiple Functions One After The Other

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, flutter-future

How can I let Flutter know to wait for one function (and therefore the future) to complete, until the next function is called?
It seems like the load() function itself completes before the loadFeed() Future is finished, how can I fix that?

Here is my current code:

```
ValueNotifier<List> data = ValueNotifier([]);
ValueNotifier<bool> loading = ValueNotifier(true);

loadAll() async {
  await load(0, 'url1');
  print("0 finished");
  await load(1, 'url2');
  print("1 finished");
  await load(2, 'url3');
  print("2 finished");
}

load(int categoryIndex, String _url) async {
  loadFeed(_url).then((result) {
    if (null == result || result.toString().isEmpty) {
      print("error");
      return;
    }
    data.value = [[],[],[],];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++) {
      data.value[categoryIndex].add(result.items[i]);
    }
    data.notifyListeners();
  });
}

Future<RssFeed> loadFeed(String _url) async {
  loading.value = true;
  try {
    final client = http.Client();
    final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(_url));

    return RssFeed.parse(response.body);
  } catch (e) {
    print("error");
  } finally {
    loading.value = false;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems like the `load()` function itself completes before the `loadFeed()` Future is finished, how can I fix that?

That's exactly what's wrong.  You do:

```dart
load(int categoryIndex, String _url) async {
  loadFeed(_url).then((result) {
    // ... bunch of code...
  });
}
```

Your `load` function calls `loadFeed`, registers a `Future.then` callback, ignores the newly returned `Future`, and synchronously returns to the caller after callback registration.  It does not use `await` to wait for the `Future` to complete, nor does it return the `Future` to the caller to allow the caller to wait for the `Future`.

It's much simpler if you use `async`/`await` instead of mixing it with the raw `Future` API:

```dart
Future<void> load(int categoryIndex, String _url) async {
  var result = await loadFeed(_url);
  // ... bunch of code...
}
```

Additionally, enabling the [`unawaited_futures` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html) in your [`analysis_options.yaml` file](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options) would have caught this problem during static analysis.

Answer (score 2):

In future functions, you can use `whencomplete`, from the documentation:

> "WhenComplete", Registers a function to be called when this future completes.
>
> The [action] function is called when this future completes, whether it
> does so with a value or with an error.
>
> This is the asynchronous equivalent of a "finally" block.

- Change `load` into a future function, and add a return value to let dart know that you are done, like this:

  ```
  Future load(int categoryIndex, String _url) async {
     loadFeed(_url).then((result) {
       if (null == result || result.toString().isEmpty) {
         print("error");
         return;
       }
       data.value = [[],[],[],];
       for (var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++) {
         data.value[categoryIndex].add(result.items[i]);
       }
      return data.notifyListeners(); //add a return here, to tell dart that this function is done.
     });
   }
  ```
- Change your `loadAll` into this:

  ```
  loadAll() async { 
  await load(0, 'url1')
  .whenComplete(() async => await load(1, 'url2')
  .whenComplete(() async => await load(2, 'url3')));}
  ```

Comment: You don't need to use `.whenComplete()` if you're already using `await`.